# .NET Workflow: Transition Between States Through Code

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4.5

I am building a simple app for bug tracking, and I am using a .NET Workflow Activity Library project with a State Machine, with the individual states representing the states for a bug - Reported, Assigned, and Completed.

I am able to use the WorkflowInspectionServices class to obtain the list of state transitions for the bug for each state. However, I am trying to:

1. Determine the current state that a particular bug is in, and
2. Change the current state, without using the trigger condition (I want to trigger the change through code when the user selects the state from the dropdown)
3. Read the value of a variable within the workflow

How can I do these with a .NET Workflow?

Comment: Just an update - I am now able to get the current state of the state machine using StateMachineStateTracker from the Microsoft.Activities.Extensions.Tracking namespace (Microsoft.Activities.Extensions is available through NuGet). The [documentation on the CodePlex project wiki](https://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Tracking%20states%20with%20WorkflowApplication) provides code snippets.

Comment: For changing the current state of the state machine, there was [a question asked earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547695/wf45-statemachine-set-state) with no answers or comments.

One 'hacky' way this can be accomplished is to set a field in the argument-object to request for a state change and to use that field in a trigger condition. However, if a transition to the requested state is not available, the state machine stays put without any indication that the requested transition is invalid.

Comment: On the MSDN forums, it has been stated that as of WF4, although the SetState implementation is being considered for a future version in [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/697f2b30-331c-44cc-9146-6f9603f84384/is-there-a-setstate-in-the-new-statemachine-activity?forum=wfprerelease). Also, the thread has a mention that specifying transitions at design-time is considered a best practice, but it does limit the scenarios in which WF can be used.